# How to upgrade multiple file of database in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

I am not able to update upgrade schema file.

I want to update database using upgrade schema file that i have already updated.

In my module i have a database table which is created using install schema file.

This is my UpgradeSchema file

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.2.0', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable( 'mageplaza_helloworld_post' ),
                'test',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'length' => '12,4',
                    'comment' => 'test',
                    'after' => 'status'
                ]
            );
        }



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

this file is correctly updated

now i want also update my table with new column like this

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.2.0', '<')) {
            $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable( 'mageplaza_helloworld_post' ),
                'test123',
                [
                    'type123' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'length' => '12,4',
                    'comment' => 'test123',
                    'after' => 'status'
                ]
            );
        }



        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

This is not work properly

Comment: Would you share what you've done so far?

Comment: i will add my file please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you have a mistake in the addColumn() definitions.
You should use 'type' instead of 'type123'.